# Unrealistic results in Gpinter

Tags: economics

I have tho following wealth tax statistic from which i want to do a Pareto interpolation using gpinter.

[image]

From this table i have extracted the percentails, their corresponding thresholds and bracket averages
[image]
Than I have entered them in R using the gpinter application as shown in the blueprint provided by the creator Thomas Blanchet.
However, I recieve unrealistic results, i.e. higher than 100% for top10 shares.
Can somebody point put where have I made a mistake?
Thank you.